# (have+something+past participle) Vs (have+past participle+something)

Tags: present-perfect, word-order

I have a confusion about word-order in present perfect tense and past perfect

tense.(The tenses that have auxilary verb)

A) I have cleaned ***all the carpets***.

B)I have ***all the carpets*** cleaned.

C)I have read ***the book***.

D)I have ***the book*** read.

it seems to me that when the sentence has a determiner like ''***all***''

( ***all*** the carpets), A and B both possible but when the sentence does not

have a determiner (like ''***all***'') just sentence c is correct ,sentence d is

incorrect.

Am I right about it ?

Which one is correct and more idiomatic, is there any difference between

sentence A-B and C-D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions **A** & **C** (*Present Perfect*) the action of the verb has been performed **by you** (**I**) , while in versions **B** & **D** (different from *Present Perfect*) it's unclear who's responsible for that action.

**B**) means all your carpets are in the process of cleaning (they are cleaned by e. g. those you've hired).

**D**) means somebody reads that book for you.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive/have-something-done

Answer (score 3):

Sentences A and C are correct, in these you are the subject.

Sentences B & D are Grammatically incorrect.

> B - I have all the carpets cleaned.
>
> > This Should Be I Have had all the carpets cleaned.
> >
> > > This would mean that you made someone else clean the carpets, meaning that you are no longer the subject
>
> D - I have the book read.
>
> > This is completely incorrect in grammatical sense.

Hope this helped you.